# Decrypt C# AES encrypted text in Java

Tags: java, asp.net, cryptography, aes

I'm implementing in Java a third party application, but some part of the application I'm get a encrypt string like this: eGlhV2xNbmdqSFBkbEhkZDNpZ3gwQT09 
and have to decrypt.

The guy who code this application is no longer here, so I need some help make a decrypt code in  Java.
this is the password :CB=Z8#P@0!N2/8$%3K-9C(5S9*FDH+0Z

```
public static class SystemCriptografia
{
    #region Atributos        
    private static string chave = "CB=Z8#P@0!N2/8$%3K-9C(5S9*FDH+0Z";
    private static SymmetricAlgorithm algoritmo = new RijndaelManaged();

    #endregion

    #region Métodos

    #region Métodos privados

    private static string base64Encode(string data)
    {
        byte[] encData_byte = new byte[data.Length];
        encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
        return encodedData;
    }

    private static string base64Decode(string data)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        string result = new String(decoded_char);
        return result;
    }

    private static string Criptografa(string valor, string chave)
    {
        byte[] ByteValor = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valor);

        // Seta a chave privada
        algoritmo.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algoritmo.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(chave);
        algoritmo.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("brasilshopsoft07");

        // Interface de criptografia / Cria objeto de criptografia
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = algoritmo.CreateEncryptor();

        MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream _cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(_memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Grava os dados criptografados no MemoryStream
        _cryptoStream.Write(ByteValor, 0, ByteValor.Length);
        _cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Busca o tamanho dos bytes encriptados
        byte[] cryptoByte = _memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Converte para a base 64 string para uso posterior em um xml
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cryptoByte, 0, cryptoByte.GetLength(0));
    }

    private static string Descriptografa(string valor, string chave)
    {
        // Converte a base 64 string em num array de bytes
        byte[] cryptoByte = Convert.FromBase64String(valor);

        // Seta a chave privada
        algoritmo.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algoritmo.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(chave);
        algoritmo.IV = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("brasilshopsoft07");

        // Interface de criptografia / Cria objeto de descriptografia
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = algoritmo.CreateDecryptor();

        MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cryptoByte, 0, cryptoByte.Length);
        CryptoStream _cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(_memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        // Busca resultado do CryptoStream
        StreamReader _streamReader = new StreamReader(_cryptoStream);
        return _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    #endregion

    public static string ToCriptografa(this string valor)
    {
        return Criptografa(valor, chave);
    }

    public static string ToDescriptografa(this string valor)
    {
        return Descriptografa(valor, chave);
    }

    public static string ToCriptografaQueryString(this string valor)
    {
        return base64Encode(Criptografa(valor, chave));
    }

    public static string ToDescriptografaQueryString(this string valor)
    {
        return Descriptografa(base64Decode(valor), chave);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and this is the java code that I'm trying to do :

```
public class Criptografia {

    private static final String AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 256;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(decryptAuthorizationString(
                "eGlhV2xNbmdqSFBkbEhkZDNpZ3gwQT09", "CB=Z8#P@0!N2/8$%3K-9C(5S9*FDH+0Z"));
    }

    private static String decryptAuthorizationString(final String authString,
            final String password) {
        try {
            // --- check if AES-256 is available
            if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING) < KEY_SIZE) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unlimited crypto files not present in this JRE");
            }

            // --- create cipher
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING);

            // --- create the key and initial vector bytes
            final byte[] passwordEncoded = password.getBytes(UTF_16LE);
            final byte[] keyData = Arrays.copyOf(passwordEncoded, KEY_SIZE
                    / Byte.SIZE);
            final byte[] ivBytes = Arrays.copyOf(keyData, cipher.getBlockSize());

            // --- init cipher
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "AES"),
                    new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

            // --- decode & decrypt authentication string
            final byte[] authBytes = Base64.decode(authString);
            final byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(authBytes);

            // WARNING: may still decrypt to wrong string if
            // authString or password are incorrect - 
            // BadPaddingException may *not* be thrown
            return new String(decryptedData, UTF_16LE);
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // failure to authenticate
            return null;
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Algorithms or unlimited crypto files not available", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you key `chave` is in no way sensitive...

Comment: Actualy that key is only numbers , encrypt string is simple numbers , like 1 ,2 , 3 .

Comment: What's the default encoding (`Encoding.Default`)? What's the problem with your Java code? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty new in code encrypt , I dont really know how to test it , i build a little Java application with that code. I get this exception one time :  Unlimited crypto files not present in this JRE.
I'll try instantiating the class and call the methods.

Comment: Yes , I test the code and get this exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unlimited crypto files not present in this JRE

Comment: enconding.Default = UTF8  , sorry for the flooding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues of your code:

- Wrong character set chosen. If `Encoding.Default` is UTF-8 in C#, then the "password" and IV encodings must also be `"UTF-8"` in Java.
- The IV is not derived from the key, but also a fixed value.
- The ciphertext is actually doubly Base64 encoded. I guess somebody took "two is better than one" too literal.

Full code:

```
private static final String AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
private static final int KEY_SIZE = 256;
private static String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(decryptAuthorizationString(
            "eGlhV2xNbmdqSFBkbEhkZDNpZ3gwQT09", "CB=Z8#P@0!N2/8$%3K-9C(5S9*FDH+0Z"));
}

private static String decryptAuthorizationString(final String authString,
                                                 final String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        // --- check if AES-256 is available
        if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING) < KEY_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unlimited crypto files not present in this JRE");
        }

        // --- create cipher
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CBC_PKCS5PADDING);

        // --- create the key and initial vector bytes
        final byte[] passwordEncoded = password.getBytes(UTF_8);
        final byte[] ivBytes = "brasilshopsoft07".getBytes(UTF_8);

        // --- init cipher
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(passwordEncoded, "AES"),
                new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

        // --- decode & decrypt authentication string
        final byte[] authBytes = Base64.decode(authString);
        final byte[] authBytes2 = Base64.decode(authBytes);
        final byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(authBytes2);

        // WARNING: may still decrypt to wrong string if
        // authString or password are incorrect -
        // BadPaddingException may *not* be thrown
        return new String(decryptedData, UTF_8);
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // failure to authenticate
        return null;
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Algorithms or unlimited crypto files not available", e);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

---

Notes:

- Using a fixed IV is insecure. The IV must be chosen randomly in order reach semantic security. It doesn't have to be secret, so it can be sent along with the ciphertext. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.
- Lose the second Base64 encoding. It just takes away space, but doesn't provide any useful feature.
- Always use a specific encoding. `Encoding.Default` is nice for testing, but it may change depending on the machine it's running on and you will lose compatibility between multiple clients/servers.
- Authenticate ciphertexts! If you don't add a message authentication code or use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, then an attacker may manipulate the ciphertext and you will not be able to determine this. This can go so far as to completely recover the plaintext of specific encrypted messages (padding oracle attack).

Comment: First of all, thanks for you answer, really helps.
I have some doubts and problems:

final byte[] authBytes2 = Base64.decode(authBytes);   Its telling that type spected is String.

Sorry but i not familiar with cryptography and at my work have no one who know. Thanks for you answer and patience.

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: I build this code with some example that i see, but I dont really undestand it, so my doubt its about he main method,  i put the encoded word and password in the call of decryptAuthorizationString method, but the main  needs a String args ,should i change that ?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` is necessary for the JVM to determine the entry point to the application. If it is different, then the application doesn't have an entry point. Keep the `args` even if you don't need them. Does this code solve your problem?

Comment: and about final byte[] authBytes2 = Base64.decode(authBytes), i put  authBytes.ToString() , can I do this?

Comment: No, `byte[]` doesn't have a useful `toString` method. You can use `new String(authBytes)` to see the intermediate result.

Comment: I not sure how test the code , i create an another class and call Criptografia.main();  but this is because i didnt really know how to test my code, I keep getting this exeption  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unlimited crypto files not present in this JRE    , Thanks for you patience, sorry but I dont really know much...

Comment: Have you installed the Unlimited Strength policy files for your JDK and JRE? Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html Java 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: It works , but i had to try in another computer, even installing JDk and JRE Unlimited Strength, Now I'll make the encrypt CODE , you have any tip ?
Thank you for everything, and for you patience. You're awesome.

Comment: It's basically the same thing, but the encoding is the other way around: first encrypt then encode (twice ... \*facepalm\*).

Comment: KKK , Thank you, I don't really understand Cryptography (how you can see), my first contact with it , was yersterday. But I'm Studying how it works , you help a lot.

Comment: I trying to make the code but I'm having some problems to undestand somethings, not sure if iI have to make another question, I not sure how wich code do,

Comment: Here is the full encryption: https://gist.github.com/artjomb/ffb2331b75bb2311ac7e8dc250a9e378

Comment: Yeah , i was doing that, but my problem is with the Types:
final byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(authString.getBytes(UTF_8));
        final byte[] authBytes = Base64.encode(encryptedData);   // here says that String cant be converted to bytes
        final byte[] authBytes2 = Base64.encode(authBytes);   // and here too

Comment: Well, that depends on the library you're using, but you can safely convert a Base64 encoded `byte[]` to string with `new String(b, "UTF-8")` and back to a byte array with `s.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: I'm Try convert but doesnt work , i think that is the library problem,this
(import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;) its saying that i dont use.

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE;


import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

Comment: Those are just warnings. If you don't use an imported class, then you can simply remove the import statement. Also, please don't use the `com.sun.*` classes. Those are proprietary APIs that are not necessarily available on every JVM. For example, I'm using `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64`, because I already have the BouncyCastle library in my classpath. You can also use a Base64 encoder from Apache: commons-codec

Comment: Its all working now , you are very kind and patience , thank you for everything.

Comment: Hi , i had another problem , maybe you can help me once more.
For te Id its working fine, but in another park of the Project guy who made the code do a crypto in a DateTime to make an  password for an user.
the crypto string came like this TbwgUFx5z+BOmcZQhO8dBMz30eJp5Q+ZKor2Z7QxFaY=
 Bur when i put in the code i get that excepion.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65533.